# Nested dictionary in VB .NET

Tags: vb.net, dictionary

I am trying to create a nested generic dictionary, but I am getting runtime error when allocating memory, how should I allocate memory
I have declared a generic dictionary as follows

```
dim tmp as generic.dictionary(of object,generic.dictionary (of int, object))
```

I have used following statement to allocate memory

```
 dim tmp as generic.dictionary (of object,generic.dictionary (of int, object)) = New generic.dictionary (of object,generic.dictionary (of int, object))
```

Regards,
Vishal

Comment: is the error a secret?  `Object` is probably suboptimal

Comment: This looks like a complexed object, so maybe create a class that defines the parts - which can include a `List(Of T)` inside it where a collection may be needed.

Comment: `int` is not a legal Type in VB.  use `Int32` or `Integer` and please read [Ask]

Comment: .NET Framework is managed memory framework, what is the case where you need to care about allocating memory if you going to use object?

Answer (score 0):

The following code compiles and executes without issue.

```
' .NET targeting: 4.6
' VB.NET version: 2012 (VB 11)

Option Strict On
Option Explicit On

Module Module1
    Public Sub Main()
        Dim tmp As Generic.Dictionary(Of Object, Generic.Dictionary(Of Integer, Object))
        tmp = New Generic.Dictionary(Of Object, Generic.Dictionary(Of Integer, Object))
    End Sub
End Module
```

Comment: True, But I was proving that that they could be dimmed and instantiated seperately.